# Text will not render

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

Some of my text will not render in the banner I am making. I do not know how to fix this.

This is my compositing, as you can see the just rendered image is now showing in the render (this happens on all of my texts except "EXELLPVP")

[image]

Comment: can you upload a wider picture? it's too small.

Comment: I just did, but it might be kind of blurry. I am taking a screenshot and do not know how I can make it higher quality.

Comment: use blender to take the screenshot , CTRL+F3 or *Window*-> *Save Screenshot* .

Comment: Is the element enabled for rendering (camera icon in the outliner?)

Comment: Is the text object shadeless ? does the scene have enough light?

Comment: Can you include a .blend file?

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/585d1l2kpyqqiaj/ExellPvP+%28actual%29+Banner.blend There is the blend file.

Comment: It does not show up as a Text Object, it shows up in  the "Data" section, is that why? If it is, how can I change it to text?

Comment: Thank you @root for you suggestion of light! I added a light and made the color of the text emit. My problem is fixed, but I am still having the problem of not being able to make the background a picture.